# Good resources on polyhedral compilation

Tags: optimization, compilers

I'm looking for good introductory resources (books, articles, notes, websites, videos, e.t.c.) on polyhedral compilation. I'm especially interested in applications related to deep learning / GPU computation acceleration.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Er, what is that ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what polyhedral compilation is.  What research have you done?  What resources have you found so far?  If you haven't done any research yet, it's probably premature to ask here.  What are the criteria for "good"?  Resource recommendation questions often don't work here very well, because they tend to be subjective (see our [help/dont-ask]); to make it work well, we need you to give specific requirements or criteria for evaluating answers.